# BootStrap DatePicker Breaks when invoked from an event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, datepicker, onchange

I am trying to invoke the BootStrap datepicker from a select menu on my form as follows ;

```
var handle_change = function () {

    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
        startDate:'2013-09-02',
        endDate:'2013-12-20'    
    });

};

$('#dropdown').on('change',handle_change);
```

This breaks the page but when I invoke the datepicker on its own like this :

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
    startDate:'2013-09-02',
    endDate:'2013-12-20'
});
```

it works. I'm trying to figure out why the code breaks when invoked from an event handler like I did in the first code snippet, thanks.

Comment: Can you show all your JQuery code? Is it wrapped in a ready event?

Answer (score 0):

What does **#dropdown** and **.input-daterange** refer to, more over you can get better help if show all your **html** and **jquery** code.

Any ways try below snippet, it may help you

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
    startDate:'2013-09-02',
    endDate:'2013-12-20',
    onSelect: $.proxy(this.handle_change, this) //make your function call here
});
```